# How to find all referenced to stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I have a stored procedure and need to change it. 
But the only way is drop and create, which can drop references!
Is it any way to check, if it is reference to my procedure.

Comment: What DB2 version/platform? By the way, dropping a routine _does not_ drop dependent routines.

Comment: I already created a copy of this procedure for my experiments, but thanks for information.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT Name as [Stored Procedure Name]
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%SP_Name%'
AND OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%SP_Name%'

Above Query would give you the stored procedures name where your Sp is used.(Edit "SP_Name" with stored procedure name you want to search with)